# case classを利用したパターンマッチで、引数の中身をListにしたくない

Tags: scala

以下のプログラムを実行したとします。

```
sealed trait Expr
case class N(n: Int) extends Expr
case class Var(x: String, a: Int, n: Int) extends Expr
case class Add(n: Expr*) extends Expr
case class Mul(n: Expr*) extends Expr

def add(xs: List[Expr]): Expr = xs match {
  case List() => N(0)
  case List(xs) => xs
  case xs => Add(xs: _*) // Add(List(N(1), N(2), Var(x,2,2)))
}

println(add(List(N(1),N(2),Var("x",2,2)))) // Add(List(N(1), N(2), Var(x,2,2)))
```

このプログラムで期待する出力結果は

```
Add(N(1), N(2), Var(x,2,2))
```

なのですが、実際の出力結果は

```
Add(List(N(1), N(2), Var(x,2,2)))
```

となってしまいます。上記のプログラムで期待する出力結果にする方法をご教示いただけますでしょうか。

どうぞよろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

<strike>`toString`をオーバーライドして、出力をいじりました。

こういうことでしょうか？</strike>

```
sealed trait Expr
case class N(n: Int) extends Expr
case class Var(x: String, a: Int, n: Int) extends Expr
case class Add(n: Expr*) extends Expr {
    override def toString() : String = "Add(" + n.mkString(", ") + ")"
}
case class Mul(n: Expr*) extends Expr

object Main {

    def add(xs: Seq[Expr]): Expr = xs match {
        case Seq() => N(0)
        case Seq(xs) => xs
        case xs => Add(xs: _*)
    }    

    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println(add(List(N(1),N(2),Var("x",2,2))))
    }
}
```

---

追記：質問はどうも「出力の結果を`Add(N(1), N(2), Var(x,2,2))`にしたい」というより、「コンストラクタ`Add(n: Expr*)`は可変長個の引数をとるが、それがAddクラスの可変長個のフィールドに格納されるようにしたい」ということのようですね。結論から言えば、Javaのクラスのフィールドの個数が動的に変化することはないように、scalaでも原理的に無理でしょう。

scalaでコンストラクタが`Add(n: Expr*)`という可変長の引数をとるものだとしても、実際には単に`n`という単一のフィールドを持ったクラスになるだけです。`Add(n: Expr*)`は引数の渡し方の見た目を変えるだけに過ぎません。

Comment: 上記の方法ですと、見た目はそのようになりますが、実際は文字列を引数に入れているだけのようにも見えます。

`sealed trait Expr

case class N(n: Int) extends Expr
case class Var(x: String, a: Int, n: Int) extends Expr
case class Add(n: Expr*) extends Expr
case class Mul(n: Expr*) extends Expr

def add(xs: List[Expr]): Expr = xs match {
  case List() => N(0)
  case List(xs) => xs
  case xs => Add(xs: _*) // Add(List(N(1), N(2), Var(x,2,2)))
}

println(add(List(N(1),N(2),Var("x",2,2)))) // Add(List(N(1), N(2), Var(x,2,2)))
println(Add(N(1),N(2),Var("x",2,2))) // Add(WrappedArray(N(1), N(2), Var(x,2,2)))
`

上記のプログラムを実行してもこのようになるので、事実上無理なのかもしれません。